# Why "make" is the correct answer to this question?

Tags: verbs

Come across this fill the blank quiz today. And not quite sure why the answer is "make"? For me, "use" sounds like a valid answer as well.

> Q: Jack, don’t forget you can ____ a mobile payment to pay taxes this year. The deadline is 5/31!

**Options:**

【A】use

【B】make

【C】hold

【D】have

Comment: Often multiple choice language questions tell you more about the questioner than about the language.  Why do you think it could be ‘make’?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the deadline ‘5/31’ supposed to represent?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey It represents that you have to pay the taxes before this date.

Comment: @Tuffy Not sure what you mean? Do you mean that both answers are acceptable?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey In the US dates are shortened to mm/dd/yy, but in the U.K. they are shortened to dd/mm/yy.  You are puzzled because you are either a US citizen or have learned US English.  So the British way of representing the 31st of May looks strange to you.

Comment: @konekoya Not quite.  Only one of the 4 can be the answer the person who set the question had in mind, I know which I think it ought to be.  But the question is testing you, not me!

Comment: @Tuffy Erm no, in the UK we would represent the 31st of May as 31/5 because it is the thirty-first of the fifth. Clearly, this is an American way of writing it because they have written 5/31 or, as I would read it, the fifth of the thirty-first

Comment: Exactly my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, "use" appears to be a valid response to me, as well. But when we consider which verbs are most commonly used with the noun "payment," it should be obvious that "to make (a) payment" is a very common idiom, whereas "to use (a) payment" is not. That is probably the reasoning behind the question.